# Wildfly: Jboss error on start-up

Tags: jboss

I am having trouble starting my jboss with

```
./standalone.sh
```

in the directory

```
/ali/wildfly-9.0.1.Final/bin$.
```

It  throws the following error

```
 15:01:37,824 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation]       
(Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: 
([("deployment" => "HelloServlet.war")]) - failure description: 
"WFLYCTL0212: Duplicate resource [(\"deployment\" => \"HelloServlet.war
\")]"
15:01:37,830 FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) 
WFLYSRV0056: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting.
```

Comment: The server reports that you've tried to deploy two "HelloServlet.war". That could be for multiple reasons, such has having two <deployment> tags named "HelloServlet.war" in your standalone.xml, or having put the "HelloServler.war" file in multiple auto-deployment directories.

Comment: try removing the "HelloServlet.war". from your standalone/deployments/ directory

Comment: i have removed the directory but there is a folder with the same name. and the error still remains.

Comment: well, just use the "~/rmdir HelloServlet " command to remove it also ant try again..

Answer (score 16):

If you are using a deploy tool, check the standalone.xml conf file or HA conf file, at the end you should to **delete** the "deployments" tag

```
<deployments>
    <deployment name="xxx.war" runtime-name="xxx.war">
        <content sha1="fb73e5d66e5184b1d4791a5cb5d61970f73c14b0"/>
    </deployment>
</deployments>
```

Comment: this saved me after 30mins of problems